# css, is px dead

Tags: css, pixel, measurement

I am thinking about future CSS best-practices. A 12px font on a new iPad or iPhone is going to be unreadable. To compensate, these devices change their definition of a pixel. When you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> on your browser, it also just changes the definition of a pixel and redraws.

Since pixels are no longer really tied to a display unit, is it time to simply abandon the pixel as a unit of measurement?

Advantages:

- Elements are easier to relate to each other (mm and cm; pt, pc, in, etc).
- Points transfer to print nicely. (Recall Netscape Navigator and printing pixel-sized fonts?)
- We are very used to referring to font sizes in points.
- Physical measurements are much easier to design with.
- Displays are getting denser and more varied.  If we say an item is 7 mm high, then it will be 7 mm high.  Using pixels, we haven't a clue what the end user will see.

Disadvantages:

- Images will always be made up of a fixed number of colored dots. A 500 x 500 image will always look best at 500 x 500 display elements.
- Javascript reports sizes of elements in pixels, and converting them to physical dimensions takes extra work.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: The problem is that I don't think an item that is set to 7mm high will actually be rendered as 7mm high. That has to factor in your monitor size and resolution, which I'm pretty sure most browsers don't.

Comment: This has been asked before .. **and** closed before.